# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar un json?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Estoy intentando filtrar un `json` pero no he llegado a la solución, estos fueron mis intentos:

El valor de  "e" es un `string`

```
// Esto sólo me da el país que seleccionó el usuario
Object.keys(prevState.currencyRates).filter((items) => items === e,);

[prevState.currencyRates].filter(() => 'COP')
```

El valor de `prevState.currencyRates` es éste: [JSON LINK](https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates), (ya iteré el `json` y solamente me da `idPais: value`)

Si abren el *link* se le descargará el `json`. Pueden usar esta herramienta en linea [app.boomerangapi.com/](https://app.boomerangapi.com/?ext)

También  intenté con:

```
prevState.currencyRates.COP
```

Y me funciona pero la cosa es que el valor de "COP" debe ser cambiante por que se modifica desde un select

El código completo:

```js
setCurrency(e) {
  const valueCurrency = Object.values(dbdefault.list.currencyCoinbase).filter((items) => items.id === e)[0];
  update((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    defaultSelect: {
      ...prevState.defaultSelect,
      currency: {
        ...valueCurrency,
        //Object.keys(prevState.currencyRates).filter((items) => items === e,)
        currencyToUSD: prevState.currencyRates.e // el valor de e no cambia 
      },
    },
  }));
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder al valor indexado de un objeto, debes hacerlo con las llaves `[`, `]`.

De este modo,

```
const getProperty = (obj, key) => obj[key];
```

Devuelve el valor indexado con `key` en el objeto `obj`.

```
const obj = {
    key1: `val1`,
    key2: `val2`,
    key3: `val3`,
    key4: `val4`,
};

const v1 = getProperty(obj, 'key1');
const v2 = obj.key1;

console.log(v1 === v2); // true
```

De este modo se puede acceder de forma dinámica a las claves de un objeto.

Espero que sirva.